# script tag inside the top of HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, performance-testing

I add my javascript files just before the < /html > tag. But one of my script calculates running time of my webpage. So I need to put one of my script in the very first part of my HTML page. Script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NREUMQ=NREUMQ || [];
    NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);
</script>
```

What is the best line to put the script into ?

```
1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="tr">
3:  <head>
4:      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
5:      <title>  example - example.com    </title>
6:       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
7:      <meta name="keywords" content="my words"/>
8:      <meta property="fb:page_id" content="12345" />
9:      
10:         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
11:       
12:         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
13:       
14:         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
15:         <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
16:         <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png"/>
17:         
18:         <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="http://example.com/"/>
19:         <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/eng"/>
20:         
21:         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/colorbox.css"/>
22:         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/demo_table.css"/>
23:     </head>
24: <body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After line three would work fine - assuming that script has a second part to calculate the total time?

Assuming you just want to see how fast your page loads, I strongly recommend grabbing Chrome and using the `Network` tab of the dev tools (press F12 to see the dev tools) to see how long components take to load. You might also want to install the Chrome PageSpeed plugin ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli?hl=en ) which sits with the rest of the dev tools. It analyses the page and makes suggestions on how you could speed it up.

Comment: Yes, just before < /html > tag I add remaining script.

Comment: Then line 3 will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put the script is always within the head tag. `<head></head>`.

You can place your script in between line 3 and line 23.

Comment: There is css scripts in line 21 and 22. If I put script to line 23, will css files be loaded before script run ?

Comment: Go with line number 3